# How to create window in tcl without title bar

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

How can I create a window in tcl using its window manager (wm) so that there is no title bar. 
wm title "abc" ; if I miss this then tcl's window manager gives its own name.

Comment: Are you really sure you don't want the title bar? The title bar is what allows users to move, maximize, minimize/iconify and close windows. Without the titlebar the window either can't be manipulated by the user or you have to manually handle stuff like window move/close on your own.

Comment: yes, That's a requirement

Answer (score 3):

To remove the window manager decorations entirely, use [`wm overrideredirect`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/9870) *before the toplevel window is first mapped* (typically immediately after creating the toplevel) to request that it be mapped as an unmanaged window; this is what things like menus and tooltips do for you behind the scenes.

```
set t [toplevel .abc]
wm overrideredirect $t 1
# Fill out the contents
```

Be aware that this can interact “interestingly” with focus management, and that on X11 you *should* also set the `-type` attribute appropriately, such as in:

```
wm attributes $t -type tooltip
```

You might instead be better in some cases to make the window into a *transient* for another window, which (usually) changes the window decoration but not quite as radical as making it override-redirected.

```
# e.g., this makes the window a transient of the main window
wm transient $t .
```

If you're making a full-screen undecorated window though, that's best done via:

```
wm attributes $t -fullscreen 1
```

Comment: And on windows you can also do `wm attributes $t -toolwindow 1`

Comment: so it is true that this cannot be applied to the `.` toplevel window? Do I need to `wm withdraw .` at the beginning of my script? thank you for this answer